# How to input command line arguments using fractions

Tags: java, command-line

I'm currently pretty new to programming and I need to learn how to input two different fractions using `command line arguments` (not using `scanner`) such as:

```
java Fractions 12/17 3/18
```

The problem that I'm facing is the **'/'** division sign within my argument. I cannot seem to separate them from my integers.

Like what GhostCat said, I need to receive a `string` of `arrays` and do proper parsing of the `string array` to determine the numbers and control the characters through the command line arguments. I'm not able to use the scanner as input.

Comment: show your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And yes, the real part is: the command line receives an array of strings. You need to do proper **parsing** of that string array in order to determine numbers and "control" chars, such as "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enter fractions directly using /. If your input needs to use this format 2/3, they you need to load it as string, then use split() method which will return you two strings that you can parse into float.

```
String fraction = args[0]; // args[0]="12/17"
String[] splittedFraction = fraction.split("/");
float numerator = Float.parseFloat(splittedFraction[0]);
float denominator = Float.parseFloat(splittedFraction[1]);
```

You might use int instead of float, depends on your requirements.

Same way you will process second fraction args[1]

EDIT: I didn't realize that you take your inputs as arguments from command line. Thanks @GhostCat for pointing that out.

Comment: You might want to add that you don't need to use a Scanner in system.in. You can as process that args array that comes in on the command line. You actually made it harder to him to understand your answer, as you are actually doing things differently.

Comment: Sorry if the question was confusing, I'll get to editing it. To make it more clearer, I don't think I can use the scanner class. I need to get two arguments (examples such as 1/7, 2/3) and input it into the command line. 

Like what GhostCat said, I need to receive a string of arrays and do proper parsing of the string array to determine the numbers and control the characters. I'm just struggling on that currently.

Comment: @Oxform My mistake, I edited my answer using command line arguments. If you are receiving multiple fractions as an argument, just put it into the loop through array args.

Comment: Hey Michal, I tried running your code but I'm getting a few errors such as char cannot be converted to string on the fraction.split('/'), and String cannot be converted to float on the splitted fractions.

Comment: @Oxform I had some mistakes there, split() function takes string instead of char, the argument is regex string actually. Then I used parseString() instead of parseFloat(). There shouldn't be mistakes, I tried to compile it and run it. Also you might want to use int instead of float, depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The command line doesn't understand / means you want a fraction, on itself. Consider 2/3 as a string, and parse it in your program instead.